# Wordplay in Suits

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Harvey and Mike were dealing with some labor dispute between nurses and the hospital. I really have no idea what the nurse meant when she said "nurses are sexy, but nurses aren't sexy." Does it mean that nurses are good-looking but not good-looking enough to officially offer them the fund?

Here's part of the script:

> Nurse: Negotiator number five. Meet the new boss. Same as the old boss.
>
> Harvey: Jameson was our last negotiator. Trust me. I'm not Jameson.
>
> N: That's what he said about the one before him. You're all the same to me. I'm over here, you're over here.
>
> H: Well, let's see if we can (H clapped N's hands tgt as if they reached a deal)
>
> N: You're going to have to buy me dinner first.
>
> H: I can do better. You're expecting me to offer you this. You're willing to settle on this. You're praying for this. Well, your prayers have been answered. And I'll even buy you breakfast in the morning.
>
> N: Not so fast, blondie.
>
> H: Prescott Hospitals is hurting as much as anyone else. You push any harder, they're going to go out of business, and nobody wins. This is the best you're going to do. And it's a deal you're ready to take.
>
> N: We were ready. But what about the new account you funded yesterday? Yeah, that's right. I know about it. This isn't my first rodeo.
>
> H: Then you also know that money's off the table.
>
> N: Money's fungible. Everything's on the table.
>
> Mike: I'm sorry, but that account was funded by donors specifically for the development of new robotics for surgery.
>
> N: I used to change bedpans for a living, Junior. I know what bullshit smells like.
>
> M: This isn't bullshit. Even if Prescott wanted to give that money to the nurses, they couldn't, legally.
>
> N: So, they're willing to raise money for equipment but not nurses? I get it. ***Nurses are sexy, but nurses aren't sexy***. Well, you need to find a way to get us access to that money, or we don't have a deal.
>
> H: That's not going to happen.
>
> N: Well, then we're done.
>
> H: You leave this table, it means only one thing.
>
> N: I know exactly what it means. We have a fully-funded strike fund, and we're going to use it. We reject your proposal.

Comment: What is the source of the above dialog?

Comment: @user3619 from Springfield! Springfield!

Answer (score 1):

> Nurses are sexy, but nurses aren't sexy.

is a play on two meanings of [*sexy*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sexy). In order,

> 1. provoking or intended to provoke sexual interest

and

> 3. interesting, exciting, or trendy

which doesn't appear to be the case when it comes to spending money on the nurses' compensation, compared to high profile stuff like "new robotics for surgery".

Comment: so basically it's saying that nurses are hot but not interesting or exciting enough like "new robotics for surgery"?

Comment: When you are speaking to investors who are primarily interested in their financial returns, yes. Advertising new technology in the health care industry will bring them new patients and more profits.